# bypass pre-commit hook for merge commits

Tags: git, git-submodules, githooks

I setup some git hooks to run some `gulp` commands on pre-commit.  I basically run `jshint`/`plato`.  I basically want to bypass these for two cases:

1. hotfix branches (master / hotfix)
2. git merge  (or find a way to do it in a way that doesn't crash on the merge commit case)

The plato gulp command runs analysis on the source and produces a /reports/ directory that tracks complexity over time.   If we do this on the hotfix branch it will result in merge conflicts when merging them back into development.  Enough talking here is the simple hook:

```
#!/bin/sh

if git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | grep '.js$' >/dev/null 2>&1
then
  git stash -q --keep-index
  ./node_modules/.bin/gulp jshint
  RESULT=$?
  git stash pop -q
  [ $RESULT -ne 0 ] && exit 1
  git stash -q --keep-index
  ./node_modules/.bin/gulp plato
  git add report/
  git stash pop -q
fi

exit 0
```

Issue right now is if i have a merge conflict on "reports" and I resolve the merge `All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.` and then commit it runs the analysis again and stages the commit and when it commits it throws an error:

> /Users/Nix/work/project/.git/modules/somesubmodule/MERGE_HEAD' for reading: No such file or directory.

The directory does exist but there is no merge head...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

So I just found a command that I think i can use to detect the "merge_head"

```
 git rev-parse -q --verify MERGE_HEAD
```

If rev-parse returns a hash that means we are currently in a merge state.  I can use that to bypass this logic.  But will wait for some better advice from more experienced individuals.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!

Comment: If you are rebasing, you can do about the same with the following: `git rev-parse -q --verify REBASE_HEAD`

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question, but how could we have the exact opposite effect? i.e, if we want to error out in case we're in a merge state.

Comment: @FlavioWuensche For skipping on merge: `(git rev-parse -q --verify MERGE_HEAD) || (skip_this_if_merging)`. For running on merge: `(git rev-parse -q --verify MERGE_HEAD) && (only_run_this_if_merging)`

Comment: Strange, but `git rev-parse -q --verify REBASE_HEAD` evaluates to `true` event after rebase was finished.
I tried `(git rev-parse -q --verify MERGE_HEAD || git rev-parse -q --verify REBASE_HEAD) || (skip_this_if_merging_or_rebasing)`

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29230164/) you could test for the existence of `$GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD` to detect a merge commit:

> Here's what you do get:
>
> - If you're using `git commit --amend` to amend a merge commit, the pre-commit hook is run as usual, but it can't really detect that this
>     is happening. The new commit will be a merge, but you can't tell.
> - If you're using regular old `git commit` to create a non-merge commit, the file `MERGE_HEAD` will not exist in the git directory, and
>     you can tell that this is not going to create a merge commit.
> - If you're using `git commit` to finish off a conflicted merge, the file `MERGE_HEAD` will exist, and you can tell that this is going to
>     create a merge commit.
> - If you're running `git merge` and it succeeds on its own, it makes a new commit without using the pre-commit hook, so you don't even get
>     invoked here.
>
> Hence, if you're willing to allow `git commit --amend` on merges to
>   misfire, you can get close to what you want: just test for the
>   existence of `$GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD` to see if this is a `git commit` that
>   is finishing off a conflicted merge. (The use of `$GIT_DIR` is a trick
>   to make this work even if the commands are run outside the git tree.
>   Git sets `$GIT_DIR` so that in-hook git commands will work right.)

Answer (score 2):

```
########################
# Setup Some Variables #
########################

REPO_ROOT_REL=$( git rev-parse --show-toplevel )
REPO_ROOT="$( cd "$REPO_ROOT_REL" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; pwd -P )"

####################################################
# Check for merge or rebase commit and abort if so #
####################################################

set +e
MERGE_HASH=$( git rev-parse -q --verify MERGE_HEAD 2> /dev/null)
set -e
if [ ! -z "$MERGE_HASH" ]; then
    echo "This appears to be a merge commit ($MERGE_HASH). Avoiding pre-commit steps."
    echo ""
    echo "EXITING ${0##*/}"
    exit 1
fi

REBASE_APPLY_PATH="${REPO_ROOT}/.git/rebase-apply"
REBASE_MERGE_PATH="${REPO_ROOT}/.git/rebase-merge"
if [ -e "${REBASE_APPLY_PATH}" ] || [ -e "${REBASE_MERGE_PATH}" ]; then
    echo "This appears to be a rebase commit (.git/rebase-apply or .git/rebase-merge exists). Avoiding pre-commit steps."
    echo ""
    echo "EXITING ${0##*/}"
    exit 1
fi
```