# How can I allow git merge commits to master but prevent non-merge commits?

Tags: git, githooks

I have a Git pre-commit hook that prevents me from committing to master unless overridden, in order to encourage developing on branch.

However I would like to automatically allow merge commits to master.  Is there a way to identify a merge commit from my pre-commit hook script?  The script looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

BRANCH=`git branch --color=never| grep '^*'|cut -c3-`

if [ "${BRANCH}D" == "masterD" -a "${GIT_COMMIT_TO_MASTER}D" != "trueD" ]
then
  echo "Commit directly to master is discouraged."
  echo "If you want to do this, please set GIT_COMMIT_TO_MASTER=true and then commit."
  exit 1
fi
```

**SOLVED:** For anyone looking for a cut-and-paste, the working version of this hook script is:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

if [ "${BRANCH}" == "master" -a "${GIT_COMMIT_TO_MASTER}" != "true" ]
then
  if [ -e "${GIT_DIR}/MERGE_MODE" ]
  then
    echo "Merge to master is allowed."
    exit 0
  else
    echo "Commit directly to master is discouraged."
    echo "If you want to do this, please set GIT_COMMIT_TO_MASTER=true and then commit."
    exit 1
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Suggestion: a more robust way to get the current branch is `branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)`.

Comment: @Jubobs: generally it's better to use `git symbolic-ref HEAD`.  One can add `-q` if needed—it would be in this case and then you'd want to exit 0, so in this *particular* case, using `git rev-parse` might well be superior anyway: for a detached head you'll just get `HEAD` back, which won't match `master`.

Comment: Not related to the question, but your `D` suffices are entirely redundant.  You would only need them if you didn't use quotes, and they reduce legibility, so just drop them.

Comment: @torek Interesting. Thanks. Taking it in...

Comment: It's also worth noting that the '--no-verify' flag will bypass the pre-commit hook. I suggest removing the 'GIT_COMMIT_TO_MASTER' section in favor of overriding on a case-by-case basis, since it's easy to forget to set 'GIT_COMMIT_TO_MASTER' back to false after overriding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I put a few comments in, but the important one here is that in a *pre*-commit hook, the commit you're about to test does not yet exist, so you can't count its parents.

Here's what you do get:

- If you're using `git commit --amend` to *amend* a merge commit, the pre-commit hook is run as usual, but it can't really detect that this is happening.  The new commit will be a merge, but you can't tell.
- If you're using regular old `git commit` to create a non-merge commit, the file `MERGE_HEAD` will not exist in the git directory, and you can tell that this is not going to create a merge commit.
- If you're using `git commit` to finish off a conflicted merge, the file `MERGE_HEAD` *will* exist, and you can tell that this is going to create a merge commit.
- If you're running `git merge` and it succeeds on its own, it makes a new commit without using the pre-commit hook, so you don't even get invoked here.

Hence, if you're willing to allow `git commit --amend` on merges to misfire, you can get close to what you want: just test for the existence of `$GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD` to see if this is a `git commit` that is finishing off a conflicted merge.  (The use of `$GIT_DIR` is a trick to make this work even if the commands are run outside the git tree.  Git sets `$GIT_DIR` so that in-hook git commands will work right.)

Comment: That looks promising.  I am happy for `git commit --amend` to require an override, so checking for `${GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD}` is exactly what I'm looking for.  I will test and if I don't hit any issues, I will accept this answer.