# Visual Studio Code/Git: Is there any way to prevent editing on master branch, yet allow merges?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

While working on projects, I want to always edit on branches other than master. Master is for working, tested code.

I sometimes forget this, and start coding on master branch. Then I have to reset changes, etc.

I wonder is there any way to make master files read-only, but still allow merges into it.

Comment: Allowing merges into it by *definition* makes it not read-only. Though assuming you're doing pull requests, you can require a review before you allow a merge. The main this is to always check which branch you're actually working on before making a commit.

Comment: if you haven't commit the new changes just create a new branch and the modified files will be moved over to the new branch and you can commit

Answer (score 5):

Another option, with VSCode 1.68 (May 2022):

> ### [Git: Branch protection](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_68#_git-branch-protection)
>
> With the new `git.branchProtection` setting, you can configure specific branches to be protected.
>
> VS Code will avoid committing directly on protected branches and will offer you the chance to create a new branch to commit to instead.
> You can fine tune this behavior with the `git.branchProtectionPrompt` setting.

That way, only new branches are created, before being merged back to `main`.

---

VSCode 1.70 (July 2022) fixes a regression reported in [issue 153787](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/153787) and illustrates how that settings work:

> - Launch the latest VS Code Insiders
> - Open a folder/workspace that contains a git repository
> - Ensure that the `scm.showActionButton` setting is enabled
> - Ensure that all three properties of the `git.showActionButton` setting are enabled
> - Use the `git.branchProtection` setting to enable branch protection for the current branch
> - Make a change to a file:
>
>   - Confirm that the "`Commit`" action button is shown and it has the `$(check)` codicon
> - Set the `git.branchProtectionPrompt` setting to `alwaysCommitToNewBranch`
>
>   - Confirm that the "`Commit`" action button is shown and it has the `$(git-branch)` codicon

Answer (score 3):

You could add a pre-commit hook ([like this gist](https://gist.github.com/stefansundin/9059706), which stop accidental commits to master)
You can adapt that [hook to bypass it for *merge* commits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27800512/6309).

VSCode should respect, through Git, that pre-commit, and you would not be able to commit right away if you are on `master`.
You would need to stash, switch branch, stash pop.

Actually, with the [new `git switch` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309) (Git 2.23, August 2019), you don't even have to stash.

The [example section of `git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#_examples) deals with your scenario (starting working on the "wrong" branch)

> After working in the wrong branch, switching to the correct branch would be done using:

```
$ git switch mytopic
```

> However, your "wrong" branch and correct "`mytopic`" branch may differ in files that you have modified locally, in which case the above switch would fail like this:

```
$ git switch mytopic
error: You have local changes to 'frotz'; not switching branches.
```

> You can give the `-m` flag to the command, which would try a three-way merge:

```
$ git switch -m mytopic
Auto-merging frotz
```

Comment: This prevents committing on the master, but it does not prevent starting to change the files.

Comment: @user9144 no, but at least you can then switch branches (while keeping your index), and apply your current changes to the right branch. See the new [`git switch` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309).

Comment: @user9144 I have edited the answer accordingly. The point is: start working from wherever, you can then switch and merge your work in progress to the right branch later on.